# Solve a inequality for values of $r$ and $\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

Once I used the polar tranforms I obtained the next expression.

$-\cos(\theta)+r^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)+b\sin(\theta)-r^3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)$

And I need to prove this inequality is positive for all values of $r$ and $\theta$. We also know that $b>0$.

I've trying to use Mathematica to solve this inequality $-\cos(\theta)+r^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)+b\sin(\theta)-r^3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)$ $\forall (r,\theta)$.

Wich kind of command I should use in my computer or what kind of analysis I should use to find this values.

Comment: Take $\theta=0$.

Comment: draw a plot for some values of $r, \theta, b$ and see what you get

Comment: @mathlove if I take $\theta=0$ I obtain $1>0$, but I need some expression with respect to $r$

Comment: are you sure that your statement is true? what is the original Problem?

Comment: @gt6989b With a Plot for $\theta,b,r$ how I'll obtain an expression for r, with respect of $\theta$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the original statement comes from a nonlinear ODE system given for

$u'=-u+u^2*v$
$v'=b-u^2*v$

then I used the transforms $u=r\cos(\theta), v=r\sin(\theta)$ and then derivate both realtions and then substitute them into de ODE system, and then I finally obtain that expression.

Comment: @mathlove $\theta = 0$, it is $-1$, I hope the sign of $\cos(\theta)$ is not negative.

Comment: @Yimin but if we use that substitution we just obtain something true $1>0$ but we can't find a expression for $r$

Comment: @IvanGarcia: For $\theta=0$, we get $\color{red}{-}\cos 0+r^2\cos^20\sin 0+b\sin 0-r^3\cos^20\sin^20=\color{red}{-}1$ which is negative. So, the expression can be negative.

Comment: @mathlove yes I know, but for what values of $r$ we can solve that expression, I mean, I need to find a expresaion of the form $r<$something

Comment: You mean to say you need to solve the inequality $LHS > 0$ for the valid region for $r$ in terms of $b$ and $\theta$?

Comment: @gt6989b that is correct, That is what I exactly want!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the inequality
$$
-Ar^3 + Br^2 + C \ge 0
$$
where $A,B,C$ are functions of $b,\theta$, that you will need to solve for $r$.

For the special case of $A = 0$, this is quadratic in $r$ and is easily factorable. For $A \neq 0$, divide by $A$ to get
$$
r^3 + xr^2 + y \ge 0
$$

Apply the cubic formula to factor this (you can find the detailed instructions here: http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html)